Authorship issues and postdoc
My supervisor and I wrote an article and submitted to xyz journal. At that time she didn't give me first authorship. I discussed this with other faculty members in my institute who also agreed that she should have given me first authorship since it was based on my phd work.
Since I couldn't gather courage to discuss this with her, I decided to write to journal. As per their guidelines, student should be the first author. The journal replied to resolve the issue within two days.
Unfortunately i was travelling and couldn't revert. After two days editor in chief rejected our paper stating that it is beyond the scope of journal and carbon copied it to me.
Now, I am applying for postdoc in editor in chief's collaborator lab. Will this ruin my chances of getting a postdoc position? My guide doesn't know any of them and will give me a good recommendation letter.
Ps: my guide had previously removed my name from author contribution section of my first author paper because of her favorite student. I requested her to mention my name. She felt offended and said that she never had student like me.
Tried getting first authorship . Landed in a problem.

The circumstances of the postdoc in question aren't clear. Are you asking if the authorship issue will impact your ability to get a postdoctoral position in the lab or one of your supervisor's collaborators?

Your question is about "whether not having a first authorship paper ruins your chance of getting postdoc position"? or it is "whether your previous supervisor can ruin your chances of getting postdoc?", you still didn't make it clear, are you a Ph.D. student? during the problematic paper, have you been her student and now graduated?

Guidelines: rules or instructions about the best way to do something.
Guidelines are what the authors should do to correctly submit a paer to the journal, not what the journal will do on the submitted paper.

I am sorry. Question is that editor in chief and that professor whom I wish to apply for postdoc are collaborators.  My supervisor doesn't know any of them and she will give me a good recommendation letter. But can the editor in chief tell his friend that I wrote their journal an email stating authorship related issues. Do they consider me a bad student who wants authorship desperately or mean one. My supervisor has tortured and abused me a lot. I fell into depression because of her and those people have no idea about this. Hope now my question is clear

carbon copied it to me --- This confused me at first, then I realized (and google-double-checked) that "cc" for email ACTUALLY IS an acronym for "carbon copy". Brought back memories of my Aug 1973 - Jun 1974 typing class in high school, in which some of our in-class assignments involved having to use carbon paper for carbon copies. Much of that class involved learning all sorts of spacing, letter headings, margin widths, salutations and such for different kinds of business letters, things I strongly suspect are entirely absent in today's school keyboarding classes!

To answer your main question, I don't see how/why you would be the topic of conversation between an EIC who handled a submission (which is confidential), and a collaborator who you wish to join as a postdoc.
However, your behavior with your current supervisor is extremely problematic, and I would strongly suggest you do not ever do that again.
#1 you said your advisor will give you a good recommendation so your relationship cannot be that poor.
#2 rather than speak with your supervisor, you went around speaking with other faculty (this would be called airing dirty laundry), which would have been fine to do if speaking with your supervisor did not yield a fair or reasonable outcome (you chose to skip the first part to avoid conflict).
#3 you contacted an EIC about a submitted paper behind your advisor's back - honestly if you were my student and I found out you did this, I would fire you on the spot.
I hope you understand this is unhealthy behavior and very unprofessional conduct. It seems you got away with it this time without your advisor finding out, and I doubt there is any chance your prospective postdoctoral advisor would either. I would not make a habit of doing this again.

I committed suicide because of traumatic marriage, abortion,  and bullying by my 2 lab members. Before this incident I was my supervisor's favorite student. After I got discharged from hospital and resumed lab. I realized that she spread in the whole institute that my marriage failed because of my fault. People starting hating me. She removed my name from author contribution section of my first author paper. I was a hardworking and sincere student who would always respect her. But she treated me with cruelty. My legs would tremble. I would eat one bread per day or one meal.

I am sorry to hear that these things have happened to you. However, your response to the situation really only hurts you because you are at the bottom end of the power dynamic. I would have suggested to you to leave as soon as you felt these problems occur, but the real issue here appears to be the need for support for your mental health and wellbeing, before you end up creating a worse situation for yourself, which will surely impact your mental health further.

The student committee decided to remove me from the hostel since my supervisor favorite student complained about me that she heard me crying at night and people are terrified. My supervisor told the committe negative things about me. They asked me to vacate hostel after I got discharged from hospital. The committee gave me few days time to vacate the hostel and  hostel warden used to shout at me. While searching home, I ended up giving rent to place where prostitution was going on. Later that night I realized that something was not good about that place. Had I shifted to that place.....

Despite all this, I  never gave up.science is my passion. She would pass comments that my sad face was spreading negativity among lab members. One year later, I discovered something novel. I was awarded young scientist award, best poster award, and travel grant to attend conference in Canada. I did meditation, and I decided to heal myself. And today I am no longer in depression. I have scars that are deep. I cry but that's ok. I believe that something good will happen. I consumed 15 anti depressants and my body took a long time to recover. Despite this, she delayed my viva by 1 year and now .

She suddenly called me and asked me to apply for postdoc. She will give me a good recommendation letter. If somebody would tell her that I had used 50ul of chemical in one day , she would believe and insult me without seeing any evidence.. my article would have been published in nature communications, had I completed  one experiment and that experiment was done. Another lab scientist didn't allow me to use his instrument because rumors were spread about me in the institute. This all is not to gain sympathy. But ... its not always student's fault.


editor in chief rejected our paper stating that it is beyond
the scope of journal and carbon copied it to me.

Editor in chief smelled issues among the authors and politely rejected it. Do not think about the two days you could not revert (?).
You basically set up a big red flag on your paper (even if they literally state "student should be the first author", this means that the paper should be submmited with the student as a first author, not that the editor will change the author order!).
For the rest of the question, it is quite difficult to read into the mind of people. Surely if the lab where you are applying is actively collaborating with your former advisor it may be difficult for you to get in, but you cannot know until you apply.
If you are granted an interview, you have the possibility to explain in a concise manner your relation with your supervisor, if asked.
Based on your answer, the interviewer may make up their mind to understand if you can be a good fit in their lab or not, but it depends mostly on (inter)personal evaluations specific to the people involved, I suspect there is no general rule, although they may ask your supervisor and get a not-so-positive feedback (no, you cannot do anything with respect to that now, be assured that in life there are more paths than burned bridges, although you have to loook for them).
tl;dr: Sometimes people do not go well along. Lack of communication may grow the disagreement from a "we agree to disagree" to a "never ever I will work with that person".
Depending on your culture, there are various way to communicate, but I am quite sure escalating problem to external organizations without having an internal discussion is bad in 99% of the culture.
To work with a collaborator of someone you already had a bad relation may not be the optimal thing, or it may be wonderful because collaborator went through your same experience, who knows.

My supervisor doesn't know either of them. She will give me good recommendation letter also.i am asking whether those people think of me as a mean or bad student. And if I apply for a postdoc in their labs, they may reject thinking if I can complain about my supervisor, I can do with others.
